# error about C macro invalid preprocessing token

Tags: c++, macos, qt

```
// define the macro
#define FATAL(S,...) qDebug("%s,%s,%d,%s:"##S,"[scribble]",__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__,##__VA_ARGS__)
// call the macro
FATAL("not supported commandid:%d",cmdid);
```

While this code works under Windows (Qt with msvc2010), when I try to compile it under macOS (Qt with clang), I get the error:::

> pasting formed "%s,%s,%d,%s:""not supported commandid:%d", an invalid
>   preprocessing token.

How can I make it work under macOS, or is there another way to do the same function?

Comment: I rather define the macro as `#define FATAL(S,...) qDebug("[scribble],%s,%d,%s:" S,__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__,##__VA_ARGS__)` See [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oyQfh7VrBF8gllUM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token ## only has special meaning of indicating an optional argument when it is placed between a comma and a variable argument: `, ##__VA_ARGS__`

This is an extension to the C language.

In your example this is done correctly for the second argument, but not for the first.

If you don't need the first argument to be optional simply remove the token ##:

```
#define FATAL(S,...) printf("%s,%s,%d,%s:"S,    \
                     "[scribble]",__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__,##__VA_ARGS__)
```

But the first argument can be optional too, using another macro to expand the string literal and the first argument, while making the first argument optional:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MERGE_EXPAND( a , ... )   a __VA_ARGS__
#define MERGE( a , ... )          MERGE_EXPAND( a , ##__VA_ARGS__ )

#define FATAL(S,...)              printf( MERGE( "%s,%s,%d,%s:",S),  \
                                  "[scribble]",__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__,##__VA_ARGS__)

int main( void )
{
    int cmdid = 12345;

    FATAL();    
    puts( "" ) ;
    FATAL( "first argument" );
    puts( "" ) ;
    FATAL( "first and second arguments: %d" , cmdid );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It's powerful.

Comment: Another question,why it is not work under macos but windows.

Comment: @Gavin Visual Studio handles this differently.